# 600 multiple case statements slowness in hive sql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdp

I have a 600+ case statements on multiple columns in my hive sql.

```
case when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_1 = 'XY' and B.response_1 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when  B.id_2 = 'XY' and B.response_2 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_3 = 'XY' and B.response_3 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_4 = 'XY' and B.response_4 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_5 = 'XY' and B.response_5 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_6 = 'XY' and B.response_6 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_7 = 'XY' and B.response_7 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_8 = 'XY' and B.response_8 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_9 = 'XY' and B.response_9 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_10 = 'XY' and B.response_10 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_11 = 'XY' and B.response_11 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_12 = 'XY' and B.response_12 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_13 = 'XY' and B.response_13 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_14 = 'XY' and B.response_14 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_15 = 'XY' and B.response_15 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_16 = 'XY' and B.response_16 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_17 = 'XY' and B.response_17 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_18 = 'XY' and B.response_18 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_19 = 'XY' and B.response_19 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_20 = 'XY' and B.response_20 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
when A.column1 = 'Y' then case when B.id_21 = 'XY' and B.response_21 = 'Y' then concat(C.data,'S','S') else concat(C.data,'S','U') end 
else concat('CGT',C.data) end as final_type
```

please help me with the alternative approach to replace the multiple case statements in hive

**Note: I have tried with UNION ALL but seems it is impacting the performance.**

Comment: Columns with names such as `id_NN` suggest a problem with the data model.  That may be the root cause of the performance issue.

Comment: thanks much @GordonLinoff . is there any alternate way to resolve this problem instead of case, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @satyha . . . I can't think of any that would reduce processing time.

Comment: @sathya I need some fillers for X and Y. Also, It seems like you made 600 columns from a JSON or text column in B. A possible solution for you: if the B.response is what only matters then you can do string search i B.response rather than expanding it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: any suggestion for redesign the flaw in the data model.